# Should we create chat application with Flutter and Django if we want good performance and efficiency?

Tags: django, flutter, chat, django-channels

I am a newbie in the chat application world but I am not new in the IT world! I want to create a chat application that may have a large user base in the future. I have researched that now days flutter is a very good option to create cross-platform apps and it is good in terms of performance. So to create that chat app in android and ios I will use flutter in front-end for sure!

But for backend, I am not so sure. I have 3 years of experience in python and Django and that's why I wanted to use Django as backend in my chat app. I have searched that there is one package of Django named Django-channels which I can use to build a chat app! But I have concerned like will django-channels be a good option to build a large chat application like Instagram or WhatsApp?

Answer (score 2):

For high-performance **web** applications Django is quite performant and good.

What you are searching for is a language or framework that can handle lots of connections, threads and users.

Another aspect you would want to consider is the scalability of your application.

You **can** definitely build a chat application on Django. `django-channels` is a good choice for building NRT applications. But I would recommend looking into other tech stacks as well. 
You should also consider using a well-established protocol such as XMPP as the base for your application.